# A code block seems to be always skipped by a preceding branch instruction.. (arm64 assembly)

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm64

There are many places I can't exactly understand in the kerne code. This is one I found just now.
In linux 5.17.0 arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S, I see a macro definition starting like this.

```
    .macro kernel_ventry, el:req, ht:req, regsize:req, label:req
    .align 7
.Lventry_start\@:
    .if \el == 0
    /*
     * This must be the first instruction of the EL0 vector entries. It is
     * skipped by the trampoline vectors, to trigger the cleanup.
     */
    b   .Lskip_tramp_vectors_cleanup\@
    .if \regsize == 64
    mrs x30, tpidrro_el0
    msr tpidrro_el0, xzr
    .else
    mov x30, xzr
    .endif
.Lskip_tramp_vectors_cleanup\@:
    .endif

    sub sp, sp, #PT_REGS_SIZE
```

Because this codes below is placed after `b   .Lskip_tramp_vectors_cleanup\@`, it will be never used.

```
.if \regsize == 64
mrs x30, tpidrro_el0
msr tpidrro_el0, xzr
.else
mov x30, xzr
.endif
```

Why is it there when it seems to be skipped anyway?

Comment: The code is actually used, just in a not-so-obvious way: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S#L713

Comment: Did you read the comment right above it?  The instruction is skipped under certain circumstances.

Comment: @Siguza I saw `.if \el1 == 0` of course. the part is skipped by the preceding branch not by the if.